# Grep contents after second instance, exclude last two words/columns

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am running this command:

```
mccli group show-members --name=/$vcenter_name/VirtualMachines/$i | tail -n +4
```

The output is:

```
/vcenter-prod.happycow.local/VirtualMachines/Backup With Space Normal     /vcenter-prod.happycow.local/VirtualMachines/Active Directory Virtual Machine
/vcenter-prod.happycow.local/VirtualMachines/Backup With Space Normal     /vcenter-prod.happycow.local/VirtualMachines/VM-Replicate     Virtual Machine
```

What I would like to extract from this output is `Active Directory` and `VM-Replicate`

Note that this output can change from environment to environment and we might have more spaces in the required field like:
`New Virtual Machine` `Another New Virtual Machine` `NoSpaceHere`

So my thought was grep for the second instance of the specific string `VirtualMachines`, as `VirtualMachines` is there at the beginning of the line too.

Then once the second `VirtualMachines` is matched, print everything after that match in that line only, but exclude the last two columns which is `Virtual` and `Machine` as this is always constant.

Could not figure out a syntax for this though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my `sed` solution for your output:

```
$ ... | sed -r 's:.*/(.*)Virtual Machine$:\1:'
Active Directory 
VM-Replicate
```

#### Notes:

- `.*/` looks from start to the last `/`:

  ```
  /vcenter-prod.happycow.local/VirtualMachines/Backup With Space Normal     /vcenter-prod.happycow.local/VirtualMachines/
  ```
- Then we look for anything before `Virtual Machine` using `(.*)Virtual Machine$` and replace the whole line with that anything

Answer (score 2):

Since GNU grep has a PCRE mode, probably the simplest way to obtain contents after a match is to use the perl `\K` modifier e.g. to greedily match everything up to the last `/` and discard it:

```
$ cat output | grep -Po '.*/\K.*'
Active Directory Virtual Machine
VM-Replicate     Virtual Machine
```

To remove the trailing portion, you can add an explicit *look ahead*:

```
$ cat output | grep -Po '.*/\K.*(?=Virtual Machine)'
Active Directory
VM-Replicate
```